# Delete files recursively matching a name on the command line (OS X)

Tags: macos, command-line

Just recently I tried out a backup utility, and wanted to back up the local copies I have of some websites on my MacBook (OS X)

Unfortunately, the utility left two files in every directory it backed up: `.shadowFileList` and `.shadowFolderFlagPlist`

I have now removed the backup from that directory, but it still left the files and I would very much like to get rid of the dotfiles.

I am not really a command line power user, but know that's the best way to do it. I suspect I would have to pipe the output of `find` to `rm`.

How do you do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
% find UPMOST_RELEVANT_PATH -name ".shadowFileList" -delete
```

obviously, do the same for any other filename you want to throw away...

Comment: I need it the other way around. I need to delete all files not of a certain file ending. How? Folders should not be deleted.

Comment: `find . ! -name "*.xyz" -delete`, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25136041/regex-egrep-finding-gz-but-not-tar-gz

Comment: I ended up with `find . -type f -not -name "*.hpp" -not -name "*.h" -not -name "*.inl" -delete` to keep folders.