# Mac -- remove all files with a certain extension from a directory tree

Tags: macos, rm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delete files recursively matching a name on the command line (OS X)](https://superuser.com/questions/89413/delete-files-recursively-matching-a-name-on-the-command-line-os-x)

I want to remove all files with extension .orig from my tree.  The tree is deep.  Is there an easy way to do that?

I will probably have to do this many times a day, with different trees.  So ease is important.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Use the `find` tool:

```
find /path -name '*.orig' -delete
```

Note that the wildcard must be quoted (either as `"*.orig"` or `'*.orig'` or `\*.orig`), as you want it to be only handled by 'find' but not by the shell.

Some operating systems might not have the `-delete` option, in which case make it invoke `rm`:

```
find /path -name "*.orig" -exec rm -i {} \;
```

Comment: I habitually add find's -x flag (`find -x /path ...`) to keep it from crossing mount points onto other volumes.  It's usually irrelevant, but I'd rather be safe than sorry.

Comment: To search in the current folder (including sub folders) `find . -name...`

Answer (score 18):

I prefer this method (very similar to @grawity) but with the type of `file` included:

`find /path . -name '*.orig' -type f -delete`

Answer (score 1):

Can you execute shell commands in bash? This would do the trick:

```
find /path/to/your/tree | egrep .orig$ | xargs rm
```